# Return of passport after a withdrawal

Tags: schengen, passports

I recently applied for a Schengen visa for France and I want to withdraw my passport as I have an upcoming trip 5 days before I applied for the Schengen visa. How many days will it take for my passport to be returned after I applied for a withdrawal of my application?

Comment: That's going to depend entirely on where you applied, but usually it's possible to just go there during opening hours and get it back.

Comment: VTC: as pointed out in comment, impossible to answer without knowing through which centre/consulate application was made. OP has not returned since posting.